# Swift 4 Fade label when start scrolling CollectionView

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview

I have question... how i can fade out label "Albums" when i start scrolling CollectionView? I tried to detect when i scroll my collection.

[image: ios]
http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/SimulatorScreenShot-iPhone7Plus-2019-01-09at12.1547030165.png

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == self.collectionViewA {
            // do something with collectionViewA
        } else if scrollView == self.collectionViewB {
            // do something with collectionViewB
        }
}
```

Comment: You should use scrollViewDidScroll and check the contentOffset and set alpha.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a UIImage fade in and fade out as I scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114746/how-do-i-make-a-uiimage-fade-in-and-fade-out-as-i-scroll)